# Lua table error?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm working on a sort of 'quiz', and I want the script to pick a random question out of a table.  There are no errors, but when I run the script, nothing gets printed out.  It seems like the for loop is just getting skipped over.  Am I doing something stupid?  Thanks for your help.

```
local Questions = {
Q1 = {"What is the magic word?", "lotion"}, --Q, A
Q2 = {"Does anyone love you?", "no"}
}

for i = 1, #Questions do
local number = math.random(1, #Questions)
local q = Questions["Q" .. number][1]
local a = Questions["Q" .. number][2]
print("HI")
print(q .. a)
end

io.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `#` operator is only valid in a sequence, i.e, an array-like table that indexed with `1`, `2`, and so on. But your table `Questions` is not a sequence. You can do it like this:

```
local Questions = {
    {"What is the magic word?", "lotion"}, --Q, A
    {"Does anyone love you?", "no"}
}

for i = 1, #Questions do
    local number = math.random(1, #Questions)

    local q = Questions[number][1]
    local a = Questions[number][2]
    print("HI")
    print(q .. a)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happen is because the length operator (`#`) is not defined for tables with indices that are not a sequence starting at 1.  From the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6):

> Unless a `__len` metamethod is given, the length of a table `t` is only defined if the table is a sequence, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some integer n. In that case, n is its length.

To fix your code, you could simply remove the "Q" prefix on your table keys:

```
local Questions = {
    {"What is the magic word?", "lotion"}, --Q, A
    {"Does anyone love you?", "no"}
}

for i = 1, #Questions do
    local number = math.random(1, #Questions)
    local q = Questions[number][1]
    local a = Questions[number][2]
    print("HI")
    print(q .. a)
end
```